# How to extract this key value from json data in Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to extract this key `9876` from the given data. This will be available in a processor in nifi and I have to extract this in a variable.

As it is on the key side or right side I dont understand how I can extract this **`"9876"`** specifically in Apache nifi.

```json
{
  "status": "pass",
  "values": {
    "WorkFlow": 0,
    "Reasons": {
      "resID": "",
      "options": {
        "9876": [
          "t1",
          "t2"
        ],
       "9875":[],
       "9874":[]
       }
     }
   }
}
```

It is a response I'm getting from an API and this can be `9876` or `9875` or `9874` any, These are ID's and can be in n numbers not only these three, I have just given an example. And I have to validate this number `9876` or `9875` or `9874`(there can be n numbers like this) and the content present in it. I mean I have to check whether there is content in `9876` or is it **empty**.

Comment: You can get it by using JoltTransformJSON processor but what's the logic behind it, I mean why should that be `9876`, but not `9875` or `9874`? I think the question is excessively downvoted  due to this reason.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan It is a response I'm getting from an API and this can be 9876 or 9875 or 9874 any, These are ID's and can be in n numbers not only these three, I have just given an example. And I have to validate this number 9876 or 9875 or 9874(there can be n numbers like this) and the content present in it. I mean I have to check whether there is content in 9876 or is it empty. Thats why need to extract this. How can I do via jolt?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Generally we extract data present on right side of variable or the value but here I have to extract this number present as key or on left side

Comment: The numbers you are searching for are the keys of "options". I don't know anything about nifi, but I think you have to loop over the keys of options. Please add a code example with what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **`JoltTransformJSON`** processor along with a **shift** transformation specification such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@values.Reasons.options": { // path to the "options" object
        "*": {
          "0": { // extracts only the first one from the repeated components 
            "$1": "" // key values of the arrays nested within the "options" object
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

in which the **null** arrays become extinct at that innermost level

Comment: I dont have to pick only first value, I have to pick all the values one by one, So for that I can remove "0" right?

Comment: @Destiel  That's not the first value, just the first component of the newly formed arrays by those attributes(9876,9875,9874). You'll see that works even if you try by adding another non-null array nested in the "options" object

Comment: @Destiel You'd get `"9876"` for `"options": {
        "9876": [
          "t1",
          "t2"
        ],
       "9875":[],
       "9874":[]
       }`, `["9876","9877"]` for `"options": {
        "9876": [
          "t1",
          "t2"
        ],
        "9877": [
          "t3",
          "t4"
        ],
       "9875":[],
       "9874":[]
       }` as examples.

Comment: How can I modify jolt if I want to extract every key(9875,9876,9874 etc) value irrespective of the fact whether there is data in it or not. Just extract the key if it is present in options.

Comment: @Destiel I suppose you want to solve the issue of your last question(`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76080877`) don't you? If so, I think it hasn't got to with Jolt which transforms JSON to JSON.

Comment: No, @Barbaros forget about everything above, I just want to ask here about the script you provided above for extracting keys in array format. My question here is : ---- You write jolt spec for the key extraction which has some value and it is ignoring the keys which are empty. "But" I need to extract all keys whether they have value or not, Every key must be extracted. For E.g:----[9876", "9875", "9874"] for "options": {         "9876": [           "t1",           "t2"         ],        "9875":[],        "9874":[]        }