# How to iterate on an array in apache nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

How can I iterate on this array in Nifi, I am extracting this array from an API response in nifi but unable to extract every index value one by one for completing my whole flow.

Example:  Need 6100 in any variable so that I can use it for further process and in next iteration need 6101 in that variable and so on.

Edit: This array is extracting like this only, it is not assigned to any named array such as arr[] or anything.

```
[ "6100", "6101", "6102", "6103", "6104", "6105", "6106", "6107", "6108", "6423", "23382", "354548" ]
```

Comment: use jsonsplit with jsonpath like `$..*` to split this json to separate flowfiles with `6100`, `6101`, etc. then process each file as you need.

Comment: @daggett how to iterate on each flowfile separately? I did the same and get each value in different flowfile but the problem is I am running this in an existing loop. So I need first flowfile in first call and then need second flowfile in second call of loop? I mean then question is how to iterate on flowfiles? Because they are also coming alltogether.

Comment: You could set order of processing for a queue. After splitting you will have `fragment.index` attribute in each new file. In nifi you should forget about loops...

Comment: @daggett can you explain a bit more please about this queue or where and how to use fragment.index  in nifi please.

Comment: each connection between two processors is a queue that could be configured how to prioritize flow files in it. you could set PriorityAttributePrioritizer. Use UpdateAttribute to set `priority = ${fragment.index}`. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#cluster-connection-summary But beware it's not an order, it's priority.

Comment: @daggett Can I do it using wait notify? If yes what can be the flow for that?

Comment: Could you give more info by what you mean "I am running this in an existing loop. ". 

Also, if you are trying to change a flow that is already available, would be great to share the process.